# AVG() function is displaying average of all employees instead of average of employees in each town per shop

Tags: mysql, count, average

I want to display the average number of employees in each town. Town can have

This is my `data_base`:

[image]

To clarify it's assumed that employers are part-timers so there may be a situation when they are currently not employed for the sake of exercising OUTER JOIN queries. They can also be assigned to more than 1 shop.

I found the way to do it is to use subquery for AVG function. In a subquery, I will use COUNT to count the number of employees for each town and each shop and the main query will get AVG of those numbers grouping by the town. However while logically I feel the query should be working, it is displaying wrong data. Below is a query that I created.

```
SELECT s.Town, AVG(a.cnt) AS `Number of employees` FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(k.EmpId) AS cnt FROM `Shops and Employees` k
INNER JOIN Shops s ON s.ShopId = k.ShopId
GROUP BY s.Town) AS a, shops s
GROUP BY s.Town
```

I expected to see something like this:

```
Town name | AVG of employees per town
-------------------------------------
town1     | 3
town2     | 5
town3     | 1
town4     | 4

Instead I get this:

Town name | AVG of employees per town
-------------------------------------
town1     | 2
town2     | 2
town3     | 2
town4     | 2
```

Basically what I get is all employes summed divided by the number of towns. I want an average of employees for each town e.g. in town1 I have 2 shops. Shop1 has 2 employees while shop2 has 4 employees. An average for town1 should be 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you're not grouping the data by shop in your employee count subquery, so that query is returning the total number of employees per town. Also, you don't need to group by town in that subquery. Without the complete table structure and sample data it's hard to be certain, but I think this is what you really want:

```
SELECT s.Name as `Town Name`, AVG(se.cnt) AS `AVG employees per shop`
FROM Shops s
JOIN (SELECT ShopId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM `Shops and Employees`
      GROUP BY ShopId) se ON se.ShopId = s.ShopId
GROUP BY s.Name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly the solution for my problem. Now It properly displays AVG value for each town. For example that 3 AVG value for town1.